# How to set timezone in Yaml date string?

Tags: java, yaml, simpledateformat

I use `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml`.

SimpleDateFormat use system timezone(UTC +6:30).

I want the yaml date output like SimpleDateFormat.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String dateString = "2015-11-17 15:30:30"; 
    /*
        SimpleDateFormat will UTC +6:30 (Myanmar Timezone)
    */
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date sdfDate = format.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println("Date 1 " + format.format(sdfDate));

    /*
        Yaml will not use.
    */
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    //yaml.setTimeZone(xxx) --> Is there way to set timezone?
    Date yamlDate = (Date) yaml.load(dateString);

    System.out.println("Date 2" + format.format(yamlDate));
}
```

output

```
Date 1 2015-11-17 15:30:30
Date 2 2015-11-17 22:00:30
```

Answer (score 1):

For parsing a YAML file, [apparently the spec is clear](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/issues/detail?id=141) that all dates without a time zone (in the `.yml`) are assumed to be UTC. So you either have to ensure the `.yml` has the expected time zone, or customise snakeyaml's parser as suggested in the link above.

For dumping data, what you want is to use snakeyaml's own DumperOptions, as per [this test code](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/source/browse/src/test/java/org/yaml/snakeyaml/issues/issue141/ConfigurableTimezoneTest.java?r=582cadc2a594031afea7e9cd47d0cb9f21039b6c):

```
DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
options.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6:30"));
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
```

Comment: Even I use as u said `Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);`. `Yaml` is still UTC timezone. If you test my program with your answer, it is still different output. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to output the date in Myanmar's time zone, but without a time zone designation, e.g. "+6:30"?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String dateString = "2015-11-17 15:30:30";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date sdfDate = format.parse(dateString);

        DumperOptions options = new DumperOptions();
        options.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6:30"));
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml(options);
        Date yamlDate = (Date) yaml.load(dateString);

        System.out.println("Date 1 " + format.format(sdfDate));
        System.out.println("Date 2 " + format.format(yamlDate));
    }

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to get snakeyaml to do what you're after (quickly). But if you dump a YAML file with a date like `2015-11-17 15:30:30`, you'll find that any other YAML-compliant parser (including snakeyaml) will assume that date is in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is best way to solve this problem.
Temporally, I have to solve like at below.

which is calculation the time different(Eg: +6:30) programmatically and append to the date string.

Example Date String : `2015-11-17 15:30:30 +6:30`.

```
    String sdfSt = "2015-11-17 15:30:30";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date sdfDate = format.parse(sdfSt);
    System.out.println("Date 1 " + format.format(sdfDate));

    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String itmeDiff = "+6:30"; --> for my timezone
    Date yamlDate = (Date) yaml.load(sdfSt + itmeDiff);
    System.out.println("Date 2 " + format.format(yamlDate));
```

Output

```
Date 1 2015-11-17 15:30:30
Date 2 2015-11-17 15:30:30
```

Answer (score 0):

My code work for this problem as per below code:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
```